# SELECT all data from a table but adding a count field for a particular column value

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I want to `SELECT` all the data from a particular table by adding a `countField` to the results that counts the number of times that the corresponding `Item.ResourceId` exists in all the results.

```
SELECT Name, ResourceId, (SELECT COUNT(ResourceId) FROM Item GROUP BY ResourceId) AS foo
FROM Item
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: You don't need the `GROUP BY`

Comment: Yeah, like Neil said, the grouping looks out of place. If anything maybe you'd want to filter the nested select statement with a where-clause to only count the items matching the ResourceId of the current line. No idea if thats the optimal form of the statement, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is your desired query

```
SELECT Name, ResourceId, COUNT(*) FROM Item GROUP BY Name, ResourceId;
```

it translates to LINQ as follows.

```
var result = items.GroupBy(item => new { item.Name, item.ResourceId })
                  .Select(group => new { group.Key.Name, group.Key.ResourceId, Count = group.Count() })
                  .ToList();
```

Or do you want this query?

```
SELECT Name,
       ResourceId,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Item y WHERE y.ResourceId = x.ResourceId)
FROM
       Item x;
```

This translates to the following LINQ expression.

```
var result = items.Select(item => new
             {
                 item.Name,
                 item.ResourceId,
                 Count = items.Count(x => x.ResourceId == item.ResourceId)
             }).ToList();
```

Given the following input

```
Name   ResourceId
-----------------
 A      1
 A      1
 B      1
 B      2
 B      2
 C      3
```

the first query yields

```
Name   ResourceId   Count
-------------------------
 A      1            2
 B      1            1
 B      2            2
 C      3            1
```

while the second query yields this.

```
Name   ResourceId   Count
-------------------------
 A      1            3
 A      1            3
 B      1            3
 B      2            2
 B      2            2
 C      3            1
```

Comment: That's it. Many thanks :)
And also thanks for everybody who tried to help

Comment: Last time I was here I hadn't opportunity to tell you that your second answer were the solution that i was looking for. And also thanks for the linq version of the query

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

SELECT resourceId, count(resourceId) FROM Item GROUP BY resourceId

Comment: It does, I've done that. The problem is that i want to have all table data listed and grouping when selecting the name would result in a sql error (names have different values and cannot be combined)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT Name, ResourceId, ResourceIdCount
FROM Item i
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT ResourceId, COUNT(ResourceId) AS ResourceIdCount FROM Item GROUP BY ResourceId
) ic
ON i.ResourceId = ic.ResourceId